# if robot configuration space is riemannian manifold, how can the Lyapunov based controller design must to proceed

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, control-theory

In the so called geometric control theory, the space is always in Riemannian manifold. Then if we want to design a controller using the manifold information, how can it seem like?